# Grails pagination is not working properly in index page

Tags: grails, pagination, grails-2.0

I am working with Grails 2.4.2. I have a view page named distGameList where I am showing the distributed game list. So when the list is over than 10 it should place other values in next page. But It's not doing it. In-fact It is creating 2 pages. I have 12 rows in that table. Now in view page 2 page is showing that's OK. But 12 rows is showing each pages although it should show 10 rows at first page and 2 rows in second page. Here are my steps below ::

in my controller ::

```
def distGameList(){
    def distributedGameList = AndroidGameDist.getAll()
    [distributedGameListInstance : distributedGameList, androidDistGameInstanceCount: AndroidGameDist.count()]
}
```

and in my view where paginate tag after ending table tag ::

```
<div class="pagination">
   <g:paginate total="${androidDistGameInstanceCount ?: 0}" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [list](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/list.html) for pagination and pass params in it.

```
def distributedGameList = AndroidGameDist.list(params)
```

or

Use this for more readable code:

```
def distributedGameList = AndroidGameDist.list(max: params.max ?: 10, offset: params.offset ?: 0)
```

Comment: which params should i use and how

Comment: shows this error message >> No property found for name [all] for class [class com.AndroidGameDist]

Comment: OK then leave findAll. Simply use `list`, like `AndroidGameDist.list(params)`

Comment: only params.max works, but params.offset with max don't work. then why offset is use for ?

Comment: `offset` is very important part in pagination. Using this grails decide which is the starting position of the next 10 records.

Comment: then why offset is not working for me? can u please help

Comment: Use this for more readable code `AndroidGameDist.list(max: params.max ?: 10, offset: params.offset ?: 0)`

Comment: May be offset is not initialised that's why it does not works. Try above code.